# Efficient boost distribution usage

Tags: c++, boost, distribution

(Rephrased the question)

I'm creating a wrapper class for boost normal distribution, and want to make it as efficient as possible.

If I use:

```
double x = 0.0;
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&,boost::normal_distribution<> > var_nor(rng, nd);
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
     double x = var_nor();
}
```

The loop works fine. My concern is that I don't want to be declaring anything unnecessarily as the method gets called many times. I tried splitting up the code and put this line in the constructor:

```
boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&,boost::normal_distribution<> > var_nor(rng, nd);
```

and have a sample method that does this:

```
     double x = var_nor();
     return x;
```

But in this case, I get an error saying var_nor() (ie. with no arguments) is not found.
Can anyone tell me what's going on with these boost declarations ie. what does the

> boost:variate_generate etc.

line actually do in with **var_nor**?
With my limited C++ knowledge, it looks as if var_nor is being defined with two different signatures.

Thanks guys
Pete

Comment: The constructor is bizarre: It defined some totally useless local variables, and it fails to initialize any of the class members. Perhaps time for a good book on C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `var_nor` is a *variable*, not a function, so it doesn't have a signature. It represents a `variate_generator` object that can *behave like* a function because it supports `operator()`.

In your code, you declare and initialize `var_nor` at the same time. The `rng` and `nd` arguments are passed to the *constructor* of the `variate_generator` object.

When you moved the declaration into your class's constructor, you were declaring `var_nor` as a *local variable* in the constructor, so it's no wonder it wasn't available elsewhere. For something to be available throughout an entire class, it needs to be a *member variable*. Declare it private in the class:

```
class NormalDistribution
{
  boost::random::mt19937 _rng;
  boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&,boost::normal_distribution<> > var_nor;
public:
  NormalDistribution();
};
```

Then initialize it in the constructor:

```
NormalDistribution::NormalDistribution():
  _rng(), var_nor(_rng, boost::normal_distribution<>(0.0, 1.0))
{ }
```

The `_rng` member needs to be declared first so that it will be initialized first. The `nd` parameter can be omitted and replaced with a temporary `normal_distribution` object passed directly to the `var_nor` constructor as shown above.

With those changes, you should be able to use the same `normal_distribution` object over multiple calls to your `sample` function, or whatever other uses you have for your `NormalDistribution` class.

In the code you've since deleted from your question, you were confusing variable declarations with function declarations. You declared `nd` as a function receiving two parameters and returning a `normal_distribution`. Likewise with `var_nor`. It was a function when you really wanted an object. You were confused because it happens to be an object that acts like a function, but it's still just an object.

Comment: Thankyou Rob, that clears it up. I'd missed recognisin the overloaded ().

Answer (score 0):

OK, working final version using Rob Kennedy's answer, for others that might be interested:

```
// normaldistribution.h
#ifndef NORMALDISTRIBUTION_H
#define NORMALDISTRIBUTION_H

#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>
class NormalDistribution
{
 public:
    NormalDistribution();
    double sample(void);
 private:
    // Use the boost random number generator
    boost::mt19937 rng;
    // Make a variate_generator OBJECT.
    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&,boost::normal_distribution<> > var_nor;
};

#endif // NORMALDISTRIBUTION_H

// normaldistribution.cpp
NormalDistribution::NormalDistribution():
  rng(), var_nor(rng, boost::normal_distribution<>(0.0, 1.0))
{
    std::cout << "Called normal distribution constructor, passing up var_nor" << std::endl;
}

double NormalDistribution::sample(void) {
    double x = var_nor();
    return x;
}

// main.cpp
#include "normaldistribution.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NormalDistribution *nd = new NormalDistribution();
    for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
      double d = nd->sample();
      std::cout << d << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see no reason for `rng` and `var_nor` to be public.